# Django + Heroku celery module not found

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to push my lastest version of my webapp live to Heroku. I'm pretty comfortable pushing to Heroku and this just doesn't seem right. For some reason I feel like Heroku is skipping my requirements.txt.  Just in case I manually installed celery on my Heroku app.

I'm getting this specific problem with celery, but if Heroku is skipping my requirements.txt this might be a bigger problem.

**1.** If I run:

```
heroku run pip install celery
```

This let's me install the package over and over, shouldn't it kick back a "requirement already met" error?

**2.** When I try to push to heroku, I keep getting a

```
File "/app/config/_celery.py", line 4, in <module>
from celery import Celery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

for the life of me I can't figure out why, I've uninstalled celery, reinstalled it locally. It's on my requirements.txt (Heroku should install it upon push to the remote). celery also seems to work locally just fine.

I'll include what I think is necessary, but let me know if I'm missing something that might provide the answer.

Here's my projects file structure:

```
POTRTMS(overall project folder)
|
+-config(holds settings)
|  |
|  +--settings
|  |  |
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  production.py
|  |  local.py
|  |  base.py
|  |
|  _celery.py
|  __init__.py (this is the __init__.py i'm referencing below)
```

**_celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import sys
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.production')

app = Celery('POTRTMS')
# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
  print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'insurance_date': {
        'task': 'insurance_date',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=8),

    },
}
```

**__init.py__**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from ._celery import app as celery_app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. Inside of my project root folder I had Pipfile and Pipfile.lock which sounds like a new way to do the requirements.txt.

I'm not sure how these files got into my project but after deleting them all is working.